# Pygame ball wrapping glitch

Tags: python, pygame, word-wrap

I am trying to make a program with pygame that randomly wraps or bounces an image of a beach ball. The bouncing works, but when it tries to wrap the ball, the ball glitches along the edge then disappears. I checked the x and y position after it disappears and it is still moving. This is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
screen.fill([255,255,255])
ball = pygame.image.load('beach_ball.png')
x = 50
y = 50
xspeed = 10
yspeed = 10
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    movement = random.choice(["wrap", "bounce"])
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255,255,255], [x, y, 90, 90], 0)
    x = x + xspeed
    y = y + yspeed
    if movement == "bounce":
        if x > screen.get_width() -  90 or x < 0:
            xspeed = -xspeed
        if y > screen.get_height() - 90 or y <0:
            yspeed = -yspeed
    if movement == "wrap":
        if x > screen.get_width():
            x = -90
        if x < 0:
            x = screen.get_width()
        if y > screen.get_height():
            y = -90
        if y < 0:
            y = screen.get_width()
    screen.blit(ball, [x, y])
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `if movement == "wrap"` block, once you change the postion of the ball, you should also add code to bring the ball *in* the window, i.e., just lines like `x = -90` aren't sufficient. Let me discuss a case where your code fails: if for example, the ball hits the right side of the window, your code tells to set the x coordinate of the ball to -90. Then, in the very next if block (`if x < 0`), your code makes `x = screen.get_width()`. Furthermore, in the next iteration of the while loop, your code can potentially choose a bounce and detect that since `x > screen.get_width()` (because the ball is still moving), the `xspeed` should be reversed. This makes the ball fall into a trap.

Basically, your code is confused as to what it should consider for bouncing or wrapping. But either of these should only occur if the ball comes from *within* the window, not from outside. But your code executes these actions even if ball comes from outside, which happens when you "put" the ball to the other side of the window for wrap. The bounce happens correctly because in that case, the ball never actually goes out of the window.

So you should do something like:

```
if movement == "wrap":
    if x > screen.get_width() and xspeed > 0: #ball coming from within the window
        x = -90
    if x < 0 and xspeed < 0:
        x = screen.get_width()
    if y > screen.get_height() and yspeed > 0:
        y = -90
    if y < 0 and yspeed < 0:
        y = screen.get_width()
```

Same should be done in `if movement == "bounce"` block for the wrap to work properly:

```
if movement == "bounce":
    if (x > screen.get_width() - 90 and xspeed > 0) or (x < 0 and xspeed < 0):
        xspeed = -xspeed
    if (y > screen.get_height() - 90 and yspeed > 0) or (y < 0 and yspeed < 0):
        yspeed = -yspeed
```